# Unit testing async rendering in ReactJS component with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a react component (16.2):

```js
import externalLibrary from 'wherever';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      externalLibrary.doStuff().then((data) => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state,
          data: data
        });
      });
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
          <div> 
            {this.state.data.map((d) => <SubComponent key={d.id}
              data={d} />)} 
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to unit test this (using Jest), lets say I want to write a test that checks that checks that a "SubComponent" is rendered for each item in the array "data". How can I do this? All of React's code samples for async code assume I want to test the async code, but in this case I want to test that it rendered correctly. You can assume that "externalLibrary" is mocked correctly, and we know doStuff() will resolve a data array with three items in it. How do I tell the Jest code to wait until the promise inside componentDidMount (doStuff()) resolves, then check the rendered component and count the elements?

(I'm using Enzyme too if that changes anything)

```js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
import SubComponent from './SubComponent';

describe("<MyComponent />", () => {
  it("Renders the correct number of SubComponents", done => {
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    // This fails because it runs before the subcomponents are rendered
    expect(wrapper.find(SubComponent)).toHaveLength(3);
  });
});
```

Comment: Would this work? `wrapper = await shallow(<MyComponent />);`

Comment: Not like that, I can't use await in a synchronous function like the one Jest is exposing and from what I can tell (I just tried) shallow is a synchronous function (it doesn't return a promise or awaitable). Even if it did, how would it know to wait for the second render?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't answer(rather workaround), but I can't comment due to low reputation :)
You can extract call to `externalLibrary.doStuff()` to separate method of your component's class. And then test this method regardless of `componentDidMount`. Calls inside `componentDidMount()` are guaranteed, because guys from React are doing their stuff well.

```js
import externalLibrary from 'wherever';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.retrieveData();
    }

    retrieveData() {
      externalLibrary.doStuff().then((data) => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state,
          data: data
        });
      });
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
          <div> 
            {this.state.data.map((d) => <SubComponent key={d.id}
              data={d} />)} 
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```